# google.script.run is not triggering the next function

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-forms

I have a function that checks if the user fills out the form correctly and checks the user's questions and answers in the Google Form that was created. I created a loading modal that should transition to whether the form was valid or not. If not valid, it will display which question in the form had the issues. However, it will not go past the loading icon. If I comment out google.script.run.loading(), it will then go to the onExtractDataFormSuccess function and call the error function in the code.gs. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The following is what I have done:

```
function checkForm(){
        var f_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        var l_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        //var email = document.getElementById('email_inline').value;
        var fullNme = f_name + " " + l_name;

        var isFNameValid = isValid(f_name);
        var isLNameValid = isValid(l_name);
        //var isEmailValid = validateEmail(email);

        if(isFNameValid && isLNameValid){
          google.script.run.loading();
          console.log("after loading");
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess).extractFormData(fullNme);
          console.log("after onExtractDataFormSuccess");
          //var response = google.script.run.extractFormData(fullNme);
          //google.script.run.extractFormData(fullNme);
          //setTimeout(confirmationPopUp,1350);
          return true;
        } else {
          displayErrors();
          return false;
        }
      }

      function onExtractDataFormSuccess(response) {
        console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
        if(!response.Success){
          console.log("encountered error in form");
          google.script.run.error(response);
        }
      }
```

Following function is in the code.gs:

```
function extractFormData(fullNme) {
  loading();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var quizAdded = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  var uniqueQuizID = Utilities.getUuid(), question_listID = uniqueQuizID.concat("-questions");
  var constructedJSON = {};
  var answer_val = false;
  var errorJSON = {};
  var email = form.getEditors()[0].getEmail();

  var quizInfo = {
    "quiz_name": form.getTitle(),
    "quiz_owner": fullNme,
    "quiz_description": form.getDescription(),
    "quiz_owner_email": email,
    "quiz_submited_date":quizAdded
  };

  console.log('Starting for loop');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    switch(item.getType()) {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        var question = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "Multiple Choice";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        answer_val = false;
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr = answers[j].getValue().trim();
            for(var x = 0; x < optns.length; x++){
                if(answr == optns[x]){
                  answer_val = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
          }
        }
        var multiJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON1: " + JSON.stringify(multiJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = multiJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        var question = item.asCheckboxItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "CheckBox";
        var optns = [];
        var answr = [];
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();//replace(/\s/g, "");
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr.push(answers[j].getValue().trim());
          }
        }
        var checkJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON2: " + JSON.stringify(checkJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = checkJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        var question = item.asParagraphTextItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "free response";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var paraJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON3: " + JSON.stringify(paraJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = paraJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        var question = item.asTextItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();
        var question_type = "free response";
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var optns = "";
        var answr = "";
        var textJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON4: " + JSON.stringify(textJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = textJSON;
        break;
    }

    if(!answer_val){
      errorJSON = {'Question':ques, 'Options':optns, 'Answer': answr, 'Success': false};
      //error(ques);
      break; 
    }
  }

  //console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(constructedJSON));

  console.log('what is answer_val? ' + answer_val);
  if(answer_val){ 
    Utilities.sleep(5 * 100)
    //sendExtractedData(uniqueQuizID, quizInfo, question_listID, constructedJSON); 
    //notifyUser();  
    return {'Success': true};
  } else {
    console.log('There was an error!');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorJSON));
    throw JSON.stringify(errorJSON);
  }
}

function error(response){
 // var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('error')
   //   .setWidth(420)
     // .setHeight(96);
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('answer-missing-error');
  html.id = response.Question;
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(520).setHeight(250), "Error");
}

function loading() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading-icon')
      .setWidth(170)
      .setHeight(76);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Loading Quiz to MOATT Database');
}
```

The following is the loading icon:

[image]

It does not show the following to show the user that there are issues in the   form they have created:

[image]

Update: The following belongs to the following files:

modal.html:

```
<script>
   function checkForm(){
        var f_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        var l_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
        //var email = document.getElementById('email_inline').value;
        var fullNme = f_name + " " + l_name;

        var isFNameValid = isValid(f_name);
        var isLNameValid = isValid(l_name);
        //var isEmailValid = validateEmail(email);

        if(isFNameValid && isLNameValid){
         google.script.run.loading();
         //CallChangeTitle();
         //console.log("after loading");
          var myRunner1 = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onExtractDataFormFailure);
          var myRunner2 = myRunner1.withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess);
          myRunner2.extractFormData(fullNme);
          return true;
        } else {
          displayErrors();
          return false;
        }
      }

      function onExtractDataFormSuccess(response) {
        console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
        if(response.Success){
          console.log("successful");
          google.script.run.notifyUser();
        } else{
        }
      }

      function onExtractDataFormFailure(response) {
        console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
        var errorJSON = JSON.parse(response.message);
        if(!errorJSON.Success){
          console.log("encountered error in form");
          google.script.run.error(errorJSON);
        } else{
        }
      }
</script>
```

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi()
      //.createAddonMenu()
      .createMenu("MOATT Add-On")
      .addItem(' Upload Quiz Q&A', 'showModeless')
      .addItem('About MOATT', 'showAbout')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function extractFormData(fullNme) {
  loading();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var quizAdded = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  var uniqueQuizID = Utilities.getUuid(), question_listID = uniqueQuizID.concat("-questions");
  var constructedJSON = {};
  var answer_val = false;
  var errorJSON = {};
  var email = form.getEditors()[0].getEmail();

  var quizInfo = {
    "quiz_name": form.getTitle(),
    "quiz_owner": fullNme,
    "quiz_description": form.getDescription(),
    "quiz_owner_email": email,
    "quiz_submited_date":quizAdded
  };

  console.log('Starting for loop');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    switch(item.getType()) {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        var question = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "Multiple Choice";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        answer_val = false;
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr = answers[j].getValue().trim();
            for(var x = 0; x < optns.length; x++){
                if(answr == optns[x]){
                  answer_val = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
          }
        }
        var multiJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON1: " + JSON.stringify(multiJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = multiJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        var question = item.asCheckboxItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "CheckBox";
        var optns = [];
        var answr = [];
        var answers = question.getChoices();
        
         for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
          var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();//replace(/\s/g, "");
          optns.push(clean);
          if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
            answr.push(answers[j].getValue().trim());
          }
        }
        var checkJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON2: " + JSON.stringify(checkJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = checkJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        var question = item.asParagraphTextItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var question_type = "free response";
        var optns = [];
        var answr;
        var paraJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON3: " + JSON.stringify(paraJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = paraJSON;
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        var question = item.asTextItem();
        //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();
        var question_type = "free response";
        var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
        var optns = "";
        var answr = "";
        var textJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
        console.log("JSON4: " + JSON.stringify(textJSON));
        constructedJSON[i+1] = textJSON;
        break;
    }

    if(!answer_val){
      errorJSON = {'Question':ques, 'Options':optns, 'Answer': answr, 'Success': false};
      //error(ques);
      break; 
    }
  }

  //console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(constructedJSON));

  console.log('what is answer_val? ' + answer_val);
  if(answer_val){ 
    Utilities.sleep(5 * 100)
    //sendExtractedData(uniqueQuizID, quizInfo, question_listID, constructedJSON); 
    //notifyUser();  
    return {'Success': true};
  } else {
    console.log('There was an error!');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorJSON));
    throw JSON.stringify(errorJSON);
  }
}
    function showModeless() {
      var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal')
          //.setTitle('Extract Quiz Q&A');
          .setWidth(550)
          .setHeight(440)
          FormApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Upload Quiz Q&A");
    }

    function notifyUser(){
      var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('confirmation-message')
          .setWidth(420)
          .setHeight(120);
      FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Quiz Uploaded Successfully');
    }
    
    function error(response){
    
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('answer-missing-error');
      html.id = response.Question;
      FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(520).setHeight(250), "Error");
    }
    
    function loading() {
      var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading-icon')
          .setWidth(170)
          .setHeight(76);
      FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Loading Quiz to MOATT Database');
    }
```

answer-missing-error.html:

```
   <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <span style="font-size:15px">Following Question Need Revision:</span><br />
              <?=id?><br /><br />
              <span style="font-size:15px">Answer provided does not match any of the available options. Please correct error and resubmit.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 bottom">
            <div class="floatImg"><img alt="Add-on logo" class="logo" width="25" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pkKdxeGRAAlotOnP8LIFO3dmbU6giI7h"></div>
            <div class="floatMOATTText"><span class="gray branding-text">Powered By MOATT</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

loading-icon.html:

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The code calls `displayErrors()` but it was not declared. Please add a [mcve] (there a lot of details that looks be unnecessary to reproduce the problem) and improve the question readability.

Answer (score 4):

When I saw your script, I thought that the reason of your issue might be due to that `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
google.script.run.loading();
console.log("after loading");
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess).extractFormData(fullNme);
console.log("after onExtractDataFormSuccess");
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
  console.log("after loading");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    onExtractDataFormSuccess(e);
    console.log("after onExtractDataFormSuccess");
  }).extractFormData(fullNme);
}).loading();
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

### Added 1:

Now, I had noticed that you had updated your question. When I saw your updated question, I think that the reason of your issue is due to the Google Apps Script side. In your situation, it seems that you are using 3 HTMLs. And, the HTML is loaded from each function of Google Apps Script. In this case, it is required to write Javascript in each HTML. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual script, as a sample modification, I added the modified script by using your showing scripts.

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
// In order to test this script, please run this function.
function main() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'main');
}

function loading(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('loading-icon');
  html.e = e;
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(170).setHeight(76), 'Loading Quiz to MOATT Database');
}

function extractFormData(e) {

  // do something

  return { Success: false, Question: "Question" }; // or {Success: true, Question: "Question"} sample response.
}

function error(response) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('answer-missing-error');
  html.id = response.Question;
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(520).setHeight(250), "Error");
}
```

##### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

```html
main

<script>
var fullNme = "sample";
google.script.run.loading(fullNme);
</script>
```

##### HTML&Javascript side: `loading-icon.html`

```html
loading-icon

<script>
var fullNme = "<?= e ?>";
console.log("At loading-icon: " + fullNme)
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess).extractFormData(fullNme);

function onExtractDataFormSuccess(response) {
  console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
  if (!response.Success) {
    console.log("encountered error in form");
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
      console.log("after onExtractDataFormSuccess");
    }).error(response);
  } else {
    console.log("after onExtractDataFormSuccess");
  }
}
</script>
```

##### HTML&Javascript side: `answer-missing-error.html`

```html
answer-missing-error
<?!= id ?>
```

### Added 2:

By guessing your expected flow using your showing script, I added one more sample script.

Unfortunately, when a dialog is opened using `modal.html`, no script is run. By this, the script cannot be used.

So, as a simple sample script, I added 2 buttons for executing `checkForm()` with and without the error.

When I saw your Google Apps Script and Javascript, when `checkForm()` is run and `loading()` of Google Apps Script is run, the initial dialog is overwritten. By this, the functions of `withFailureHandler` and `withSuccessHandler` on `modal.html` are not run. I think that this is the reason for your issue.

If you want to open other dialogs of `notifyUser()` and `error()`, it is required to run the script on the Google Apps Script side.

So, in this additional sample script, by simplifying your script, I propose a sample script for achieving your goal.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

From your script, please run the function `showModeless()`.

```js
function extractFormData(e) {
  loading();


  // do something.
  Utilities.sleep(2000);


  if (e) {
    dispError("Sample error.");
    return;
  }

  return notifyUser();
}

function showModeless() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('modal').setWidth(550).setHeight(440);
  FormApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Upload Quiz Q&A");
}

function notifyUser() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('confirmation-message').setWidth(420).setHeight(120);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Quiz Uploaded Successfully');
}

function dispError(response) {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('answer-missing-error');
  html.id = response.Question;
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(520).setHeight(250), "Error");
}

function loading() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('loading-icon').setWidth(170).setHeight(76);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Loading Quiz to MOATT Database');
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

##### `modal.html`

As a sample, "run checkForm() with no error" button runs without error. "run checkForm() with error" button runs with error. You can test both situations.

```html
<input type="button" value="run checkForm() with no error" onclick="checkForm()">
<input type="button" value="run checkForm() with error" onclick="checkForm('Error')">

<script>
function checkForm(e) {
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onExtractDataFormFailure).withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess).extractFormData(e);
}

function onExtractDataFormSuccess() {
  console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
  google.script.run.notifyUser();
}

function onExtractDataFormFailure() {
  console.log("ENTER onExtractDataFormSuccess");
  google.script.run.dispError(errorJSON);
}
</script>
```

##### `answer-missing-error.html`

```html
answer-missing-error
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="google.script.run.showModeless()">
```

##### `loading-icon.html`

```html
loading-icon
```

##### `confirmation-message.html`

```html
confirmation-message
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="google.script.run.showModeless()">
```

#### Testing

When the function of `showModeless()` at Google Apps Script is run, a dialog is opened using `modal.html`.

1. When a button of "run checkForm() with no error" is clicked, a dialog of `loading-icon.html` is opened, and the Google Apps Script continues to be run. And, when the script is finished, a dialog of `confirmation-message.html` is opened. When the `ok` button is clicked, a dialog of `modal.html` is run.
2. When a button of "run checkForm() with error" is clicked, a dialog of `loading-icon.html` is opened, and the Google Apps Script continues to be run. And, when the script is finished, a dialog of `answer-missing-error.html` is opened. When the `ok` button is clicked, a dialog of `modal.html` is run.

#### Note:

- From your provided information, I thought that this flow might be your expected flow.
- This sample script is a simple sample script for explaining your current issue and your goal. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. From `The function you see is not in the google apps script but rather a html file that calls the code.gs`, in this case, your Google Apps Script works fine. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in my proposed modification, after `loading()` was run, `extractFormData(fullNme)` is run. In this case, if an error occurs, please tell me.

Comment: I have tried your approach and it does not run this extractFormData(fullNme). It does execute the loading icon. I have provided a little more explanation on what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. Now, I had noticed that you had updated your question. When I saw your updated question, I think that the reason of your issue is due to the Google Apps Script side. In your situation, it seems that you are using 3 HTMLs. And, the HTML is loaded from each function of Google Apps Script. In this case, it is required to write Javascript in each HTML. Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual script, as a sample modification, I added the modified script by using your showing scripts. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: so the loading and error html are being called in the index. the function you see are in index and not in the other html files.

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand `so the loading and error html are being called in the index. the function you see are in index and not in the other html files.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Answer-missing-error and loading-icon only have html and not javascript. the index file has the functions that I have mentioned that call these html's to render the modal in those htmls. I would like to transition from one html to another

Comment: @Roberto Flores Although, unfortunately, because of my poor skill, I cannot imagin your whole script, when I saw your added Google Apps Script, 2 HTML files of `answer-missing-error` and `loading-icon` are used. And, unfortunately, I cannot know the script for loading HTML including `checkForm()` in your Javascript. So, in this case, can you provide your whole script? Because I have only your showing information. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. About `I have provided the code.`, I have to apologize for my very poor skill. Unfortunately, from your current showing script, I cannot imagine your whole script. When I can understand your whole script, I can think of your situation and solution. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: what code are you looking for to clear the issue

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. In this case, it's the script for correctly replicating your current issue. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Comment: @ Tanaike: I have updated the question to show where is in each file. I hope this helps clarify what it is doing. If not, please let me know

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for your reply. I would like to confirm about your showing script. In your added scripts, those are your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue in your question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Those are partially completed scripts (specifically referring to code.gs as there are other functions that do not affect the current issue). The other files are complete.

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. I had already mentioned the method for achieving your goal by proposing the sample script because I cannot see your whole script. But, unfortunately, it seems that my proposed sample script was not useful for your situation. This is due to my very poor skill. I have to apologize for my very poor skill.

Comment: @Roberto Flores So, in the current stage, in order to correctly understand your current situation that my proposed script was not useful, I asked about your whole script. When I saw your added script, for example, `modal.html` doesn't run the script. So, I thought that it is required to confirm your whole script reflected my proposed script. If you cannot provide your whole script, please tell me.

Comment: In the modal.html, it is where it runs the script. These are the three lines that start it:   
        var myRunner1 = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onExtractDataFormFailure);
          var myRunner2 = myRunner1.withSuccessHandler(onExtractDataFormSuccess);
          myRunner2.extractFormData(fullNme);

Comment: loading() is being called in extractFormData function in code.gs

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. In your showing `modal.html`, I think that no script is run when the dialog is opened. If you are using this HTML, I think that this is the reason for your issue. How about this?

Comment: I added the code where it shows the dialog (modal.html) to the user

Comment: @Roberto Flores By guessing your expected goal using your provided information, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? I think that by the added script, you can confirm the reason for your issue. Please test this script and understand the flow.

Comment: I am not sure why I would need to add 3 scripts run in the 3 html's? Per my understanding, the other two merely act as pop up's

Comment: @Roberto Flores Thank you for replying. About `I am not sure why I would need to add 3 scripts run in the 3 html's?`, I show them for explaining the flow. About `Per my understanding, the other two merely act as pop up's`, can I ask you about `the other two` you are thinking?